# Selecting most recent record from multiple tables

Tags: sql

Newbie to SQL, just stepped out of my comfort zone. I'm using MySQL in a WPF application.

I have three tables in my database.

Patients:

```
ID | Name | ...
```

Referrals:

```
ID | FK_Patient_ID | ...
```

Visits:

```
ID | FK_Referral_ID | Date | FollowUpDate | FollowUpInterval | ...
```

The 'FK' fields are foreign keys into the other tables. So a visit belongs to a referral, and a referral belongs to a patient.

I want the get the *most recent* visit for each patient (or referral, since you can't have a visit without a referral) and get the following:

```
patients.ID | patients.Name | visits.FollowUpDate | visits.FollowUpInterval
```

What I'm trying to do is get a list of patients who have missed their follow up visits.

Hopefully this is a no brainer for you SQL people out there...

Comment: does the ID in visits table are auto increment and unique? What I would do is to order the visits according to their in descending order to get the most recent record

Comment: or use WHERE referral.ID=(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM referral), if a single record is required

Comment: ID in visits table is auto increment and unique

Comment: @cha Tried that, it gives me a list of all patients... with or without visits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   p1.ID
        ,p1.Name
        ,v1.FollowUpDate
        ,v1.FollowUpInterval
FROM    Patients p1
        INNER JOIN
        Referals r1 ON p1.ID=r1.FK_Patient_ID
        INNER JOIN
        Visits v1 ON r1.ID=v1.FK_Referral_ID
        INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  MAX(v.ID) AS ID
        FROM    Patients p
                INNER JOIN
                Referals r ON p.ID=r.FK_Patient_ID
                INNER JOIN
                Visits v ON r.ID=v.FK_Referral_ID
        GROUP BY p.ID) v2 ON v1.ID=v2.ID
```

Comment: With a couple fixups (just typos) this works perfectly, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this works with MySQL, but here's one way that you could do it in SQL Server, and I think it's portable:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.NAME, v.FollowUpDate, v.FollowUpInterval
FROM Patients p
    JOIN Referrals r ON p.ID = r.FK_PatientID
    JOIN Visits v ON ON r.ID = v.FK_Referral_ID
    JOIN (SELECT r.FK_Patient_ID, MAX(v.Date) AS [Date]
            FROM Referrals r 
                JOIN Visits v ON r.ID = v.FK_Referral_ID
            GROUP BY r.FK_Patient_ID
         ) x ON p.ID = x.FK_Patient_ID
                AND v.Date = x.Date
```

Basically, you use a subquery to find the most recent visit by patient, and then join it back to your original tables to pull back the rows that match that value.  This only works if there was one row with that date.

Answer (score 0):

I used the script as below on PostgeSQL and it worked!

```
SELECT p.ID, p.NAME, v.FollowUpDate, v.FollowUpInterval
FROM Patients p
    INNER JOIN Referrals r ON p.ID = r.FK_PatientID
    INNER JOIN Visits v ON ON r.ID = v.FK_Referral_ID
    INNER JOIN (SELECT r.FK_Patient_ID, MAX(v.Date) AS "Date"
                FROM Referrals r 
                INNER JOIN Visits v ON r.ID = v.FK_Referral_ID
                GROUP BY 
                r.FK_Patient_ID
                ) x ON p.ID = x.FK_Patient_ID AND v.Date = x.Date
```